# Better usability if form inputs have a background highlight?

Tags: forms, input, highlight, long

I'm designing a pretty long form right now and am curious if it attracts the eye more and focuses users on filling out input fields if they're slightly highlighted if there's no values in there yet.  Like this: [image]

Comment: Do you mean highlighting *all* empty fields like this, or just the currently selected on-focus one?

Comment: @JonW Highlighting all fields.

Comment: I'm going to a/b test it and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers, by default, highlight active form elements. So I'd suggest that highlighting it certainly a common and, as such, expected UI interaction. As to whether or not you need to create your own active style, that likely depends on all sorts of factors regarding your specific project.